# Music when Izuku is summarizing the fight

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

My Hero Academia, Season 3 Episode 7, [11:00] -> [11:40]

Does someone know what's the music playing in the background when Izuku is talking about the fight ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That music is from **My Hero Academia Soundtrack disk 2** and it is called ***People Always Reaching for the Top (Tsuneni toppu o nerau mono 常にトップを狙う者)***

I could only find it inside a playlist so, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IDjbJcAhRA&list=PLBGT0Gf50F_dzpSQpXEJVZePI6je32jZj&index=47) you have the song and all the OST.

**PS:** Go to 0:48 and you will hear what is in the anime